# Make resource xml configurable, while make tests in java?

Tags: java, xml, testing, junit, apache-commons-io

I have to test over 100+ different situations and for every one I need external xml which to be read and parsed.
I use:

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(
                this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path),encoding);
```

For example my test xml:

```
<container xmlns:dmc="http://example.com/common">
    <object id="1369" checkedParamter="in" class="Class1">
...

</object>
</container>
```

But I have to test with ivalid id , with missing id, with existing id. Then I need **checkedParamter** to have 3-4 values and to combine all the combinations with id attribute. For every test now I create new **xml** and the only difference is is these two attributes **id** and **checkedParamter**.
I wonder if there is easy way to read the xml and to use the same structure but to pass these values from my test.

```
 <container xmlns:dmc=" http://example.com/common">
        <object id= ${valueId} checkedParamter=${valueChechedParamter} class="Class1">
    ...

    </object>
    </container>
```

Then I will use one xml and will put the desire values at the beginning of the test. I do not technology or way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is having a seperate file with `${valueId}`, like you already have.

We are going to use the following features of JUnit to accomplish our goal:

- [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) - Used for a simple list of our incoming data

We store the following file into the `resources` section of our project:

```
<container xmlns:dmc=" http://example.com/common">
    <object id= ${valueId} checkedParamter=${valueChechedParamter} class="Class1">
        ...
    </object>
</container>
```

We then start our test:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class XmlInputTest {

@Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                 { 1369, "in" }, 
                 { 1369, "out" }, 
                 { 753, "in" }, 
                 // etc.... 
           });
    }



@Parameter(value = 0)
public int id;

@Parameter(value = 1)
public String checkedParamter;

@Test
public void mainTest() {
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(
         this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("template.xml"),encoding);
    xml = xml.replace("${valueId}",String.valueOf(id)).replace("${valueChechedParamter}",checkedParamter);

    // remaing test....
}
}
```

The advantage of using this method of test running is that you have a simple list of inputs to test.

Comment: Excellent, man you saved me 10 hours xmling.
 But I would like to make abstraction one level higher. To specify or not the whole attribute so ${id=value}, not only the value. If I do that the xml is invalid. is there a way to workaround that?

Comment: What you then can do is loading the xml in a xml parser, and adding/removing properties based on that. You can add a `@Before` test method that runs before the main test is run, to create the xml outside the testing scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this at the start of your tests.

```
Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put("valueId", "1");
properties.put("valueChechedParamter", "0");

String propertyRegex = "\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(propertyRegex);

int i = 0;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(xml.length());
while(matcher.find()) {
    result.append(expression.substring(i, matcher.start()));
    String property = matcher.group();
    property = property.substring(2, property.length() - 1);
    if(properties.containsKey(property)) {
        property = properties.get(property);
    } else {
        property = matcher.group();
    }
    result.append(property);
    i = matcher.end();
}

result.append(expression.substring(i));
String resultXml = result.toString();
```